# NSButton: Action on Element within a Custom View

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, webview

Sorry for the complicated title, but it's hard to explain.

This is the hierarchy I have:

```
Custom View
    Custom View
        Push Button
    Box
WebView
WebView
```

The way my code works, is that the 'Box' has a 'setContentView' to one of the 2 WebViews shown above. So basically the Box can have a different WebView at any time.

I have the Push Button, which I want to assign to 'Go Back' on the WebView. But I need this button to 'Go Back' on the WebView which is within the Box.

So whenever the WebViews are switched around, the Push Button should link itself to whichever WebView is in the Box, and visaversa.

Is this even possible?

Thanks in advance everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had an IBOutlet for your box (called theBox) defined in whichever custom view your button's action method is in, you can just use this in that action method:

[(WebView *)self.theBox.contentView goBack];

Comment: this worked perfectly for me, and in very little code. Thanks v much.

Answer (score 1):

> So whenever the WebViews are switched around, the Push Button should
>   link itself to whichever WebView is in the Box, and visa versa.

Why not use a more conventional arrangement? Make the view controller the button's target, and have the action in the view controller take whatever action is appropriate. In this case, that would be adding the appropriate web view to the box.

Views normally don't know anything about how the application works. They just do what the controller tells them to do.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, if I understand you correctly, I should make a new View Controller Class and link the IBAction of the button to it, but how would I make that button 'goBack' on the WebView within the custom view? Keeping in mind that the WebView changes? Thanks again